# Use a specific font for emojis

Tags: configuration, fonts, fontconfig, emoji

i’d like to use the pretty Segoe UI Symbol emoji.

I installed the font by copying it over from my windows install, and awesomely enough, my system falls back to it for all emoji that my main font doesn’t have. But all (black and white) emoji existing in my main font are used.

How can I tell fontconfig to prefer “Segoe UI Symbol” for certain unicode ranges (the ones defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji))?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to prepend the Emoji font like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="family" mode="prepend_first">
      <string>Emoji One Color</string>
    </edit>    
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

The Emoji font is going be be used for the emojis even if the main font has glyphs for the emojis.

Comment: sure, but if it also contains glyphs for non-emoji codepoints, it will be used for those codepoints as well. e.g. Segoe UI Emoji has glyphs for a set similar to the latin-1 codepoints.

Comment: @flyingsheep, yes, it won't work so well then. (Even, without this, this setup cause some issues.)

Comment: This returns the desired font if I run `fc-match sans` for example, but fonts do not render for me :(